# Remove the last bar from D3 bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

This may be a simple question, but if we have a bar chart which is built using `D3.js` then how can I remove just the last bar?

Comment: At which point in time? At creation? Later? On Event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can remove the last bar

```
k = d3.selectAll("rect")[0];
k.pop().remove()
```

But the best way, would be to remove the last data set from the data array which makes the last bar.